# What is the best way to search an Oracle CLOB column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to search a CLOB column and am looking for the best way to do this, I've seen variants online of using the DBMS_LOB package as well as using something called Oracle Text.  Can someone provide a quick example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle Text indexing is the way go. You can use either CONTEXT or CTXRULE index. CONTEXT can be used on unstructured document where CTXRULE is more helpful on structured documents.

[This](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/csql.htm#i997677) link will provide more info the index types & syntax.

The most important factor you need to consider is LEXER & STOPLIST.

You can also read the posts on asktom.oracle.com

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5533095920114

Answer (score 1):

What is in your CLOB and what are you searching for ?

Oracle Text is good if you are searching for words or phrases (which is probably what you have in a CLOB). Sometimes you'll store something 'strange' in a CLOB, like XML or the return value of a web-service call and that might be a different kettle of fish.

Comment: It will be words or phrases in the CLOB, I'd like to perform some kind of wildcard search like "%KEYWORDHERE%

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this just recently and came up with the following solution (uses Spring JDBC)

```
String sql = "select * from clobtest where dbms_lob.instr(myclob, ? , 1, 1) > 0";
return (String) getSimpleJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations().queryForObject(sql, new RowMapper<Object>() {
  public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    String clobText = lobHandler.getClobAsString(rs, "myclob");
    return clobText;
  }
}, searchText);
```

Seems to work pretty well, but I'm going to do some performance testing to see how well it works under load.